# Principal fundamental matrix solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had the following linear system:

$x'=-ay$

$y'=ax$

which yields the solution $z(t)=(cos(at),sin(at))$. It is now telling me to find the principal fundamental matrix solution $A(t)$ at initial value $0$ such that:

$X'(t)=A(t)X(t)$ and $X(t) = (cos(at),sin(at))^T, X(0)=I$. Using the above information I end up with the matrix $A(t)= \begin{bmatrix}0 & -a\\a & 0\end{bmatrix}$ however I am sure the process involves the exponential function?

Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: The one you found is the coefficient matrix of the systm. Now you have to solve the equation $X'=AX$.

Answer (score 2):

There are MANY ways to find the matrix exponential, for example Maisam H. shows one (there are at least a couple a dozen ways to find it).

Maybe you are learning how to use the eigenvalues and eigenvectors to find the solution $x(t)$.

If so, for your matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -a\\a & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

The characterisitic polynomial is $|A - \lambda I| = \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & -a \\ a & -\lambda \end{pmatrix} = 0$.

This gives: $\lambda^2 + a^2 = 0,so, \lambda^2 = -a^2$, yielding $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm ia$.

You should get an Eigensystem as follows:

$$\lambda_1 = -ia, v_1 = (-i, 1)$$

$$\lambda_2 = ia, v_2 = (i, 1)$$

Armed with this information, we can write the [*Jordan Normal Form*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) as:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -a\\a & 0\end{bmatrix} = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -i & i\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -ia & 0\\0 & ia\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

From this, we can find the matrix exponential as:

$\displaystyle e^{At} = P \cdot e^{Jt} \cdot P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} -i & i\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} e^{-iat} & 0\\0 & e^{iat}\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\ -\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

We know that $e^{ \pm iat} = \cos (at) \pm i \sin (at)$, so have:

$$e^{At} = P \cdot e^{Jt} \cdot P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos (at) & -\ sin (at)\\ \sin (at) & \cos (at)\end{bmatrix}$$

At $t = 0$, we get the zero vector $X_0$, thus our final solution is:

$$x(t) = X_0 e^{At} = X_0 \begin{bmatrix} \cos (at) & -\ sin (at)\\ \sin (at) & \cos (at)\end{bmatrix}$$

Aside: a very nice approach to finding the matrix exponential for a $2x2$ is Putzer's method, but for some reason, I don't see it used a lot.

Regards

Comment: But what is X_0? I got a 2x1 matrix [1,1]^T...

Comment: You provided $X_0 = I$, that is, the identity matrix - so just pre-multiply by that.